# Get markup for post without loading into the template

Tags: loop, themes, templates

I am writing a shortcode plugin that displays posts according to some parameters passed into the shortcode. I have the `wp_query` to get the posts and now I am trying to get the markup for the posts according to the theme's template files.

In essence, [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is exactly what I want... except that it directly loads the markup into the template. I want to get the markup for the content, perform a little post-processing and then return the markup for the shortcode. Essentially,

```
$listings = new WP_Query(...);
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $markup .= get_template_part('content', $post->post_type);
}
return $markup
```

Except this obviously isn't the way that `get_template_part` works. How do I get the markup for a post without rendering the markup into the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a WordPress way to do this and looking at the WP source, it looks like this probably will never really be possible. However, I was able to get a solution using vanilla PHP by redirecting standard output into a buffer and loading the buffer into a variable.

```
$listings = new WP_Query(...);
ob_start();
while ( have_posts() ) {
    get_template_part('content', $post->post_type);
}
$markup = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $markup
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for just the content from a post before it gets loaded into a template, then you're probably looking for `get_the_content()`.

Comment: No. That isn't quite what I am looking for. Since I am using this as a shortcode, the normal functions like `get_the_content` don't work properly... From the docs, "Any string returned (not echoed) by the shortcode handler will be inserted into the post body in place of the shortcode itself."

Comment: In otherwords, I need to get the markup and return, instead of `echo`, which is akin to what `get_the_content` would do.